# Trying to get background fetch working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10.3

I'm trying to get a background fetch up and running in an iPhone app.

I'd like the app to notify the user with a notification that a new item has been fetched from a server.

And added the following code in appDelegate & I have the background mode checked in Capabilities:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
                 launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(30)
  .
  .
```

}

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> ())
{
    debugPrint("**** Fetch complete")
}
```

When I minimise the app how can I get it to send a notification to the user that a new item is available? What am I missing above?

Thanks

Comment: There is a pretty good [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) of _Background Modes in iOS_. You can look at the ___Background Fetch___ option for your case.

Comment: Thanks for that, I got that to work, kind of, I can get my app to execute a fetch request once,  however, I can't get it to  fetch some data every hour for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your server sends a remote notification to the device and then the device does what it has to such that an item becomes available. In that case, all you need to do is schedule a local notification to fire immediately and that will show the user a notification respectively.